# transcedental equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

How to solve a equation like `3^x + 4^x = 6^x` in MATLAB . I want the solution exact to eight decimal digits .

I tried a very simplistic way but there is not enough memory for that . Since I know the solution is between `1` and `2` , I thought of creating an array `x = [1:10^-9:2]` and then use these arrays to find the value of correct `x` . I know this is very naive method .

How does one go about solving such equations in MATLAB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html):

```
>> f = @(x) 3^x + 4^x - 6^x

f = 

    @(x)3^x+4^x-6^x

>> x0 = [1 2]

x0 =

 1     2

>> format long g
>> fzero(f,x0)

ans =

            1.293174075673
```